# Como pasar a swing un programa ya previamente hecho en java?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo este programa:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Escribe un numero");
        int num = lector.nextInt();
        
        calcFactorial(num);
        
        lector.close();
    }
    
    public static void calcFactorial (int num) {
        int factorial = 0;

        factorial = num;
        int i;
        if (num>=0) {
            System.out.print(num+"!=");
            for (i = num-1; i >=1; i--) {
                
                if(i==1) {
                    System.out.print(i);

                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(i+"x");
                    factorial=factorial*i;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(" Su factorial es: "+factorial);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No es un numero positivo");
        }
    }
}
```

Como puedo pasarlo a java swing para que me salga el scanner con un textfield? y el resultado en una nueva ventana al pulsar calcular por ejemplo? No se muy bien como hacer esto en java Swing, el programa ya lo tenia hecho yo en java y ahora me resulta complicado trasladar en java swing ya que no lo he hecho nunca alguien me podría guiar? (ya tengo el java swing configurado y he inciado una nueva clase, he estado tocando un poco el diseñador de java swing para ver como funcionaba pero estoy completamente en blanco sobre como podría trasladarlo a java swing). Muchas gracias de antemano.

**edit**

Después de las respuestas y de intentarlo yo misma este es el resultado, aunque no logro enlazar calcFactorial con el boton de calcular como se me pronpone en las respuestas:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Main {

    private JFrame frmCalculaUnFactorial;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main window = new Main();
                    window.frmCalculaUnFactorial.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Main() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmCalculaUnFactorial = new JFrame();
        frmCalculaUnFactorial.setTitle("Calcula un factorial");
        frmCalculaUnFactorial.setBounds(450, 200, 450, 300);
        frmCalculaUnFactorial.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frmCalculaUnFactorial.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblIntroduceUnNumero = new JLabel("Introduce un numero para calcular su factorial");
        lblIntroduceUnNumero.setBounds(98, 27, 315, 14);
        panel.add(lblIntroduceUnNumero);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Calcula");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                calcFactorial(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(149, 96, 136, 23);
        panel.add(btnNewButton);
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(128, 50, 184, 20);
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
    }
    
     public void calcFactorial (int num)  {
            int factorial = 0;
            String formato = "";
            factorial = num;
            int i = 0;
            if (num>=0) {
                for (i = num-1; i >=1; i--) {

                    if(i==1) 
                        formato += i;
                    else
                    {
                        formato += i + "x";
                        factorial=factorial*i;
                    }
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmCalculaUnFactorial, this, num + "!=" + formato + " Su factorial es: "+factorial, i);  
            }
            else 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmCalculaUnFactorial, this, "No es un numero positivo", i);   
        }
    }
```

Dando como resultado lo siguiente:

[image: resultado visual]

Comment: No necesitas usar la clase `Scanner` en `swing`. Simplemente crea un TextField en la cual el usuario ingrese el número y posteriormente, creas un botón, y que al momento de hacer clic en el, calcule el factorial y esto se lo hace a través del evento  `actionPerformed`.

Comment: a vale entonces el scanner ya no lo uso? pero creo que tengo un mareo mental de los gordos, yo tengo una especie de interfaz donde puedo añadir botones y label, textfield, etc. como puedo hacer que por ejemplo al pulsar el boton calcular vaya a la parte de mi codigo donde realiza la operacion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Como puedo pasarlo a java swing para que me salga el scanner con un textfield?

La clase `Scanner` se **suele** utilizar para leer datos desde consola, por ende, al trabajar con interfaces gráficas no lo necesitas y simplemente puedes hacer uso de la clase `JTextField` para poder leer la entrada que escriba el usuario en el cuadro de texto.

El método `calcFactorial` lo debes de invocar cuando ocurra X acción, en este caso, cuando el usuario haga clic en el botón y esto se logra usando el método [addActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)) que herada la clase `JButton`. Obviamente se le debe pasar al método un  objeto que implemente la interfaz [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), debido a que, la rutina `addActionListener`, invocará internamente el método `actionPerformed` cuando ocurra una determinada acción.

**Ejemplo:**

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JFactorial extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;

    public Frame() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() 
    {
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jTextField1.setText("");
        jButton1.setText("Calcular");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {                                         
        calcFactorial(Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));
    }        

    public static void calcFactorial (int num) 
    {
        int factorial = 0;
        String formato = "";
        factorial = num;
        int i;
        if (num>=0) {
            for (i = num-1; i >=1; i--) {

                if(i==1) 
                    formato += i;
                else
                {
                    formato += i + "x";
                    factorial=factorial*i;
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, num + "!=" + formato + " Su factorial es: "+factorial);  
        }
        else 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No es un numero positivo");   
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {
                new Frame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Como te puedes dar cuenta, modifiqué un poco el método `calcFactorial` y esto se debe porque ya no tiene sentido usar el método `println` (porque esto es para consola). Por esa razón, todo el formato estará en una variable de tipo `String` para que el resultado se vea de esta forma (tal como lo hacías en consola):

```java
4! = 4x3x2x1 Su factorial es 24
```

Y para mostrar dicho resultado, se lo logra con el método `showMessageDialog` de la clase [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

**Actualización:**

Debes cambiar:

```java
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmCalculaUnFactorial, this, num + "!=" + formato + " Su factorial es: "+factorial, i);
```

Por:

```java
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmCalculaUnFactorial, num + "!=" + formato + " Su factorial es: "+factorial);
```

Comment: Hola!!! creo que empiezo a entenderlo un poco más! :) he añadido en mi pregunta el codigo generado por el diseñador ya que es un tanto diferente y no logro saber como agregar el metodo calcFactorial al boton generado por este diseñador. De todas formas muchisimas gracias!!!!!!

Comment: @azucarilla he actualizado la respuesta. Ya no hace falta pasar la instancia actual con `this`, porque eso lo hace `frmCalculaUnFactorial`.

Comment: wau ahora si muchisimas gracias!!!!! ahora si!!! llevo toda la tarde intentándolo!!

Comment: @azucarilla En este enlace: [showMessageDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) hay diferentes sobrecargas de este método (es decir, tienen distintos parámetros).

Comment: Voy a hecharle un vistacito!! Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es construir una aplicación gráfica con un JFrame y un JPanel y añadirle un JTextLabel y un botón que será el que ejecute la acción que queremos.

Después pondremos ese botón a la escucha de un evento mediante la interfaz ActionListener y en vez de pedir el numero a través de un Scanner lo guardaremos en una variable mediante el método getText() de JTextLabel.

Ya solo nos quedaría imprimir ese texto donde quisiésemos.

También te recomiendo hacer que el método calcFactorial devuelva un String con el resultado para imprimirlo directamenete.

Te muestro un código que he realizado imprimiendo el resultado por consola, pero se podría mostrar en cualquier sitio.

```html
public class clase_prueba {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

  MiFrame miFrame = new MiFrame();
  miFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 }
}

class MiFrame extends JFrame{

 public MiFrame(){
  add(new MiPanel());
  this.setBounds(200, 200, 450, 600);
  setVisible(true);
 }
}

class MiPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

 JLabel texto;
 JTextField campo1;
 JButton mostrar;

 public MiPanel(){
  texto = new JLabel("Introduce un número");
  campo1 = new JTextField(20);
  mostrar = new JButton("Mostrar");
  add(texto);
  add(campo1);
  add(mostrar);
  mostrar.addActionListener(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
  int numero = Integer.parseInt(campo1.getText());
  System.out.println(Calculo.calcFactorial(numero));
 }
}


class Calculo{

 public static String calcFactorial (int num) {
  int factorial = 0;

  factorial = num;
  int i;
  if (num>=0) {
   System.out.print(num+"!=");
   for (i = num-1; i >=1; i--) {

    if(i==1) {
     System.out.print(i);

    }
    else {
     System.out.print(i+"x");
     factorial=factorial*i;
    }
   }
   return " Su factorial es: "+ factorial;
  }
  else {
   return "No es un numero positivo";
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hola!!! creo que empiezo a entenderlo un poco más! :) he añadido en mi pregunta el codigo generado por el diseñador ya que es un tanto diferente y no logro saber como agregar el metodo calcFactorial al boton generado por este diseñador. De todas formas muchisimas gracias!!!!!!